# Can I use JSON data in RequestMapping in Spring MVC

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

I'm thinking the answer here is probably no, but just in case.

I'm doing something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="data.json", params="query=overview")
public String getOverview(@RequestBody MyRequest myRequest) {
    [...]
    return "overview";
}

@RequestMapping(value="data.json", params="query=detail")
public String getDetail(@RequestBody MyRequest myRequest) {
    [...]
    return "detail";
}
```

and the client is POSTing JSON data, which is deserialized by Jackson on the way in and bound to the MyRequest parameter, all working nicely.

However, I don't like the query type having to be specified in the URL of the requests. What I would like is to include the `query` parameter in the JSON object and use that to drive the `@RequestMapping`. Is this possible?

If not, I guess I will implement a single mapping and have that method delegate to others based on the incoming data, but that feels like a step in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do does not work out of the box.

If you don't like the param why don't you add the qualifier to the URL like so:

`@RequestMapping("/overview/data.json")`

`@RequestMapping("/detail/data.json")`

If you absolutely need the functionality you mention, you could implement a custom `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` that would do what you want by extending that class as is done [here](https://github.com/rstoyanchev/spring-mvc-31-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/samples/mvc31/requestcondition/mvc/ExtendedRequestMappingHandlerMapping.java).

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I've considered a similar solution like using "overview.json", "detail.json" etc. - the client can extract the relevant query information from the JSON before posting, but I was hoping there might be a solution on the Spring side, as it seems like an obvious gap in the existing mechanisms.

Comment: @CupawnTae I see what you are saying :)

Comment: I've tweaked the question slightly to be clearer. It may be that the answer is "no", in which case I guess I'll accept this answer :) However, I'm interested that you said "out of the box" - did you have anything non-box-related in mind that might achieve it?

Comment: I was thinking that you could implement something like this on your own, but I have not found what you would have to change. I'll give it another shot and let you know

Comment: Looks like a good starting point, but I guess at that level I wouldn't have access to the parsed JSON object, would I? In fact, would I have access to the request body at all? It's starting to feel like this should be "file a feature request with the spring guys". FYI I'm probably going to go with "overview.json", "detail.json" etc. but I feel I should leave the question open for a while in case anyone knows of a full solution (or feels like writing one), or there is any relevant discussion/documentation anywhere - I'd be surprised if I'm the first to want to do it. Thanks for giving it a go!

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible if you remove the params.  You have to have something distinct between the two mappings.  If you are intent on getting rid of the params, best you could do is have a single method/mapping and call your services or whatever other logic you have according to what the value of query is in your MyRequest object.

```
@RequestMapping(value="data.json")
public String getOverviewOrDetail(@RequestBody MyRequest myRequest) {
    if (myRequest.getQuery().equalsIgnoreCase("overview")) {
        [...]
        return "overview"
    } else if(myRequest.getQuery().equalsIgnoreCase("detail")) {
        [...]
        return "detail"
    }
}
```

Since both methods are unmarshalling to the same object, you don't really need two separate methods/mappings.

Comment: yeah, this is basically the "single mapping delegating to other methods" approach I mentioned in the question. But on the "something distinct" point, bear in mind that "params" already works for POST data, but only when it's x-www-form-urlencoded. The difference here is only in the way I'm encoding the request body. It's great that Spring offers @RequestBody to bind the data, but it would be even greater if that support extended into other areas, in particular the request mapping. Thanks for the additional confirmation though

Comment: Gotcha.  I honestly don't see anything wrong with doing it either way -- using a single method or using params like you are now.  If you didn't have spring, you'd be reading the request parameters in a plain old servlet and doing the same thing.  Using the params to separate the methods is just a convenience brought about by using spring.  Just my .02

Comment: My objection to the query string is probably a hang-up from dealing with browsers that strip query strings on POST requests (many moons ago, and probably bad mobile browsers). The "if ladder" approach bugs me for a few reasons. Sure, if I didn't have Spring I'd be doing something different, but then I chose to use Spring, and this is the kind of thing that Spring does, albeit not for JSON request bodies. And it's not just about convenience - it's about extensibility (can add/remove methods/classes without changing the ifs), unit-testability, etc. They'll probably add it eventually anyway :)